# microSD card performance issue

Tags: sd-card, hardware, performance

I have some microSD cards and I noticed a weird behaviour: larger microSDs give lower results!

For example, using them on my Note 8, I get these results:
Code:

```
 64GB -> R: 70MBs W: 35MBs
128GB -> R: 60MBs W: 30MBs
```

While if I test them on my PC, I get the same performance:
Code:

```
 64GB -> R: 80MBs W: 40MBs
128GB -> R: 80MBs W: 40MBs
```

*same brand, same model, only size differs
**tested with multiple microSD cards

**Why?**

Honestly I'm *shocked* about those results! I always knew the opposite: larger storage (microSD in this case) gives better results[[1]](https://www.howtogeek.com/248827/why-are-smaller-ssds-slower/)...

Does this do not happen with microSDs too?

Comment: Might be software issues

Comment: yes, it could be... but I can't find a logic behind that! Do you have any ideas?